# performing the same query on two different servers but one seems to fail

Tags: php

I have shared hosting with two different hosting providers.

I have the smallest DB query ever (no stress)

all I do is simply echo out some info from a table, nothing crazy:

```
$loop_query = "SELECT * FROM my_table";

$sl = mysql_query($loop_query, $db_connect);

while ($db = mysql_fetch_array($sl)){

echo $db['name'], $db["age"];}
```

Now I test this on **Server A**, everything works fine.

But on **Server B**, it fails.

I either get a blank page or i get a browser error: connection closed by remote server.

Now I have a few other pages on server B which involve DB queries, and they work fine.

I'm completely lost.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Does the database table "my_table" exist on Server B? Are you using mysql_connect() with the right parameters on Server B? Is the login info different on Server B? There are many reasons why a connection would fail, and without more information it's hard to diagnose.

Comment: I don't think it has anything to do with the connection. I've attempted to simply place an echo statement right at the top of the page (before anything else) to just echo out a simple string, yet that fails. But check my edit. It works now, but then stops working after 10 mins then works again....time to call the hosting company and put on my angry voice.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Things to check:

1. Stray weird characters in your file on the server that's not working.  I've seen this happen before, and it's hard to debug.
2. Check your shared host's error log file - should be available in the cpanel.
3. Check for error logs in the web site folder (or immediately above it).
4. put an echo after the mysql_query function call, and before the while loop.  Try using an echo mysql_error to see if there are any errors.

If you find things in log files, please come back and update your question.

Comment: what do you mean by weired characters? It's working now, but it will fail again, and then work again... its defiantly a server issue. I just cannot see how other pages work with it...

Comment: a non-printable character.  Anything that's not normal ASCII, unless it's a string or outside <?php tags.

Comment: If I had to guess, I'd say it's most likely a database connection issue.  not necessarily credentials, but a flaky or crashing mysqld, or mysql on a different server and network problems.  I saw your edit with the echo.  what if you put an echo above the while loop?

Comment: That's what I tried. Above everything else. Yet the echo statement does not get executed.